# xslt- interpolating multiple variables immediately adjacent

Tags: xml, xslt

this should be a simple question, but i've had no luck in a few experiments.

I'm using XSLT to transform XML into CSV. I have my key output elements defined as variables, thus-

```
<xsl:variable name="sep" select='"&#9;"' />
<xsl:variable name="crlf" select='"&#13;&#10;"' />
<xsl:variable name="lf" select='"&#10;"' />
```

The input XML looks like this-

```
<unit>
    <def>60 s</def>
    <name><singular>minute</singular></name>
    <symbol>min</symbol>
    <definition>period of time equal to 60 seconds</definition>
</unit>
```

Some units have both singular and plural names, some have only one, and some have no name (strange, but that's what i have to deal with).

When I detect a unit with no `<name>` element I need to output two empty columns (two separators) to the CSV.

In this snippet of XSLT-

```
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="name">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="name" />
            <xsl:value-of select="$sep" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$sep" />
            <xsl:value-of select="$sep" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
```

having two separate `<xsl:value-of select="$sep" />` statements works but it seems verbose. Is there a tidier way?

Using `<xsl:value-of select="$sep$sep" />` doesn't work. Nor does using`$sep$sep` either directly in the otherwise clause, or embedded in an xsl:text element.

Is the XSLT parser just too limited to interpolate more than one variable into a string, or is there a formulation i'm missing?

--UPDATE--
My reading of various xslt guides indicates that the syntax `{$sep}{$sep}` should work in the literal body of an xsl:match element, but that's not working either.

Comment: You could use `<xsl:value-of select="concat($sep, $sep)" />` - but it's the same thing you have now (except perhaps less readable).

Comment: The expression language of XSLT is XPath, the value of the `select` attribute of `xsl:value-of` is any XPath expression so start with an XPath tutorial.

Comment: So which "xslt guides" suggest there is an "`xsl:match`" element? In XSLT 3 in a sequence constructor you can use so called "text value templates" https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#text-value-templates which would allow you to use e.g. `<xsl:template match="foo">{$sep}{$sep}</xsl:template>` which would be the closest to the updated snippet you have shown (requires the use of the `expand-text="yes"` attribute on the `xsl:template`or an ancestor).

Comment: You are correct, i'd mis-remembered <xsl:template match="...  as <xsl:match. However if the approach shown is an XSLT 3 feature then that's not an option as I think i'm stuck with XSLT 1 for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

> having two separate  statements works but it seems verbose. Is there a tidier way?

As I mentioned in a comment to your question, you could use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat($sep, $sep)" />
```

but there is no real advantage to be gained by this. On the contrary, it makes the code less readable - and some (me included) would say it adds an unnecessary calculation before writing to output.

IMHO, a  better way to streamline your code would be:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="name">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="name" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$sep" />
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
<xsl:value-of select="$sep" />
```

since the second separator is independent of the condition.

---

> --UPDATE-- My reading of various xslt guides indicates that the syntax `{$sep}{$sep}` should work in the literal body of an xsl:match element, but that's not working either.

Get better reading materials. `{$sep}{$sep}` is syntax for [attribute value template](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#attribute-value-templates). Since you're outputting text, it is completely irrelevant to your situation.